# Change DNS (windows server) ; math IP with domain

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system

I have a windows server 2003 and the Ip of server is :74.62.x.x . and now i buy a .com domain . and now i want match the ip with domain . 
what am i going to do ? 
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

You can create an "A" record under the SOA for your domain. Your registrar (where you purchased your domain) is a good starting point in sorting that out.